# defining shortcut to exit ipython

Tags: command-line, ipython

I like IPython from command line, but I am annoyed by a few things. One is how painful it is to exit. For example, typing `exit` or `CTRL-D y ENTER` is too long.

Is there a way to define my own 'shortcuts'? For example, so that pressing just `q ENTER` quits the IPython interpreter?

Comment: `--no-confirm-exit` flag, either in the commandline or config file.

Comment: Ok, that is already quite nice :) Not as quick as finding a way to wire the  exit to jus typing q though ;)

Comment: `q=exit`.  Do a `type(exit)` or `exit??` to see how that's defined.  My config is set up to 'exit' without confirm, but ask with ^D.  I haven't paid attention to that kind of setup detail in ages.